# Combine Html.Action() and jQuery's load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got a couple of PartialViews between which I dynamically choose and load the one I want. I do it like:

```
if(condition)
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load(@Url.Content("/Controller/DoOneThing");
else
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/Controller/DoAnotherThing");
```

Which works as a charm. But when things got to the point when I need to update those PartialViews I receive no parent page, only partial, which is expectable.

I would have no problem like this if I would able to use

```
$("#viewPlaceHolder").load(Html.Action("DoAnotherThing", "Controller"))
```

but apparently I'm not.

So how could I combine these two things or which other approach should I take?

Comment: html.action executes that action and return view in server side, by load method you can get same thing in client side.Can you clear your question?

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 Yes they do the same thing. But using jQquery's load() I can switch between PartialViews dynamically, but can't update them and for Html.Action() is the opposite. My question is about achieving both: dynamical change between views and update of them, theoretically, I suppose, it could be achieved by combining them.